# Why did you need to save something in gorilla session?

Tags: go, session, session-cookies, session-variables, gorilla

I'm a beginner with gorilla session ( and cookies in general ) and i've been experimenting with it.
In the doc they have this code :

```
session, err := store.Get(r, "session-name")
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}

// Set some session values.
session.Values["foo"] = "bar"
session.Values[42] = 43
// Save it before we write to the response/return from the handler.
err = session.Save(r, w)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
```

From my understanding of session you would need an user upon succesfull login to receive a session "token" and then store it into the Store. 
It seems that this line `store.Get(r, "session-name")` is doing just that, where in reality " session-name" would be the sucessfully authenticated user id. 
The goal here is to be able to retreive and compare the session token on futur request.( right ?)

What i'm not understanding is what are those value that are saved :

```
// Set some session values.
session.Values["foo"] = "bar"
session.Values[42] = 43
```

What are we using them for ? Is it to store extra data that would be retreived when the cookie is sent back to us ? Are stay stored in the back end ? or encoded and added to the cookie the same way a JWT would encode extra data in the payload ( like the role of the user etc.. )

It seem to me that only the first step is necessary but i'm not sure about the rest especially since `store.Get()` with no argument is supposed to generate a session as explained in [the doc example "  // Get a session. Get() always returns a session, even if empty."](https://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/Sessions) id so i could save it in my database/redis/in memory and not  use the rest at all.

I feel like i'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The store.Get method uses the request object to get the sessionid, then gets the session data from the store, and then creates the session object.

session.Values uses a map to save the session data. Reading and writing session.Values is to manipulate the session data. Finally, the session.Save method is called to save the data from the new serialization to the store.

Comment: What would you put in the session data ( Values) ? additional information on the user ?

Comment: I can save username userid ,i use jwt.

Comment: request header: Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHBpcmVzIjoxNTkwMzkxNjAyLCJuYW1lIjoicm9vdCIsInVzZXJpZCI6MX0.BsyRw-k-Z8AuxyW_68nBKpOLtybmiiEpQLQNLe942B0

Comment: @user7952151, the session data is arbitrary. It's up to you to decide what information you need to transport from one request to the next. If you can't think of anything, you don't need sessions, because storing this data is their only purpose.

Comment: Ok so i can store the userid , role id ,etc..  I thought it was more of a JWT thing to do things like that to be able to be " stateless " and avoid extra calls to the database whereas with session cookie you just had the cookie to identify your user and you needed to query your db for the extra data.
Is that data signed ? and passed alongside the cookie ? or just stored in the backend store ?

Comment: i thought only the session id would be passed to the user without anydata in it (unlike a jwt payload ) . and the rest pulled from the backend.